# Clicking same spot in a row does not fire the OnClick event

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

Ok , I have a few  `TCubes` with the `OnClick` like so

```
 procedure TForm2.cubeClick(sender: TObject);
begin
  handleCubeClick(Sender);
end;
```

and then HandleCubeClick like so

```
Procedure TForm2.HandleCubeClick(Sender: TObject);
var
cube:TCube;
oldCubeClick: TNotifyEvent;
begin

  try
    cube:= Sender as TCube;
      //save old hadler
        oldCubeClick := cube.OnClick;
      //clear it to disale
        cube.onclick := nil;
    if setblocks then
    begin
      label4.Text := 'cubed clicked';
      totalblocks := totalblocks +1 ;
      CreateCube[totalblocks]:=tcube.Create(self);
      CreateCube[totalblocks].Visible := true;
      CreateCube[totalblocks].Name := 'cubename'+inttostr(totalblocks);
      CreateCube[totalblocks].Position.x := cube.Position.X;
      CreateCube[totalblocks].Position.Y := cube.Position.y;
      CreateCube[totalblocks].Position.Z := cube.Position.Z -1;
      CreateCube[totalblocks].Material.Texture.CreateFromFile(gamedir+'\pics\'+blocktype);
      CubeData[totalblocks] := blocktype;
      CreateCube[totalblocks].Material.Lighting := false;
      CreateCube[totalblocks].Material.Modulation := TTextureMode.tmReplace;
      CreateCube[totalblocks].Parent := viewport3d1;
      CreateCube[totalblocks].OnClick := cubeClick;
      CreateCube[totalblocks].OnMouseDown := mousedown;
      label4.Text := 'cube made: '+inttostr(totalblocks);
    end;
  finally
    //Reset handler again to enable
    cube.OnClick := OldCubeclick;
  end;
end;
```

So when I left click on a cube it should create another cube on top of it.  If i right click it will remove the cube via OnMouseDown

```
procedure TForm2.mouseDown(Sender: TObject; Button: TMouseButton;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single; RayPos, RayDir: TVector3D);
var
  cube: Tcube;
begin
  if button = Tmousebutton.mbRight then
    begin
    cube := Sender as Tcube;
    cube.Destroy;
    end;
viewport3d1.Repaint;
end;
```

issue is , if i click the same spot on one of the cubes it never fires the OnClick event thus no block is added. any idea how to fix this?

Edit due to comments:
These are all global var as of now

```
  SetBlocks : boolean;
  totalblocks : integer;
  CreateCube : array[1..10000] of tcube;
  cubeData : array[1..10000] of string;
```

Setblocks 
 - is set true once a user clicks on one of the images , that set what type of image is on the block. I have checked this and when the main issue happens setblocks is true still.

```
 procedure TForm2.Image1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 updateblocktype('Lava.bmp');
 setblocks := true;
end;
```

Totalblocks
-is just the totalblocks on the game, currenly used to create the next cube in the array. Starts at 1 and 1 is added everytime a block is created. also when i have the main issue, the value of totalblocks does not go up.

-cubedata is just a quick way i used untill the cube class is comblete, it saved the name of an image, Thus when a map is loaded it will pull the image name for that cube. Thus cube[totalblocks] will have the image cubedata[totalblocks]

Comment: You didn't implement the code I posted to your other question correctly. You should read it again, and pay attention to where (and how) I placed the `try`.

Comment: @KenWhite the issue is you had cube1  but it could be any of 500+ cubes that where clicked. Thus i have to get the cube.  Thus the code `cube := sender as TCube`  has to be , before the `oldcubeclick := onclick` and `onclick = nil`

Comment: That's fine, but all three of those lines should be **before** the `try`, as I said (and demonstrated in my other post). You set something up (those lines, `try` something, and then the finally cleans up what you set up in the first place. The compiler will generate warnings on your code for variables that might not be inialized; it won't on my version. *Turn on hints and warnings for your code.*

Comment: Setting the handler to nil achieves nothing because input events are queued. Your event handler is not re-entrant, thank heavens

Comment: @KenWhite i did try to put all 3 above the try and also below , i just happen to copy the verson where it was below. But it did not make a difference still same issue.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan so what do you suggest is causing this issue?

Comment: No idea. I'm just telling you that it's important to understand input messages and messages queues. Ken gave you poor advice in your previous question.

Comment: @David: As I gave no *advice* in his previous question, I don't understand how it can be *bad*. For the 10th time, I **answered the question asked there**. If you have a better answer to it, write it. If you disagree with my answer, downvote it. After doing either of those, let it go and move on instead of running on about it.

Comment: @David: Certainly. See any of my comments to you in that other thread. Are you having reading difficulty? I've explained my answer to you there several times. I don't see how repeating it here is going to improve your understanding. (and it belongs in that other question anyway, not this one.

Comment: @KenWhite dave please clean this up now?

Comment: @GlenMorse You need to provide more information in order to get an accurate answer. Is `setblocks` a property, method or field? If property or field, what changes it? The `CreateCube` array - how is it declared? How is its size determined? (If you have a property writer for `totalblocks`, you should provide that too.

Comment: PS: What's the `CubeData` array all about?

Comment: As for now it saves the image on a cube till I create the cube class. Which is almost done and set block is Boolean just go true as long as they gave selected an image to add to the blocks

Comment: @CraigYoung i have updated the question with the extra information, i dont think it will help or maybe it will but its now in main question too. near bottom See Edit.

Comment: Your question would be easy to solve, and you'd get a good answer, if there was an SSCCE.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan whats SSCCE

Comment: Use the web to answer that. You could answer a lot of your own questions if you used websearch and read the documentation. That's how I answer your questions.

Comment: I dont know alot, and dont want to search for everything i dont know. as i would be searching non stop forever.. thus i guess i really dont care what SSCCE is then  lol.. but i am honest LD

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you have the file, just tell me how to fix this...just once dont make me search!  I am tried of searching on this issue..its been 3 days and iam stuck

Comment: If you cannot type 5 characters into a search engine then you cannot be helped. You expect us to do it for you. That is rude. So, I won't help. Not until you show that you are prepared to put the effort in.

Comment: i could but yea i dont want to ... 5 chars is alot, then there is reading it all , and trying to understand it. Then i am sure it will involve me having to do something else. maybe another link or two... but as of now it dont intrest me.. i am willing to bet it something about how to ask a question.

Comment: Do you want an answer or not?

Comment: @David Short, Self Contained, Correct Example

Comment: Yes. That's it. With one of those I'm sure many of us could answer your question quickly and well.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan not sure, but i belive i have all ready done that, if anything i could remove some of the code but there is not really much there.. the other things was asked for .. And other then that..i have about 8 sentences..

Comment: I guarantee that if you provided an SSCCE, you would get an answer rapidly.

Comment: @Glen - I cannot duplicate the problem here with the test case in your previous question.

Comment: @sertac you have to click in same spot with out moving mouse

Comment: here is link to full zip file. I have tested this on two computers, and should save you trying to duplicate the problem? http://www.filesplat.com/~shared-download?id=5S61Z3KGY5OIKSV0POAVDL1YRSJAXPJK

Comment: @Glen - I was doing that. Tried it again, it would appear I can duplicate it *sometimes*, particularly after the first click. Anyway, I see the problem. *edit:* I don't think that behavior is related with your code.

Comment: After putting an OutputDebugString in WM_LBUTTONUP case of WndProc in platform.win, I can never duplicate the problem. Removing it, I can duplicate the problem after the first click. Just to note that it seems very much to be related with the framework.

Comment: Sorry, I gave up. After running the application outside the debugger once, I was never able to duplicate the behavior.

Comment: i was starting to think it was an xe2 problem?

Comment: @Glen - That would be my guess, yes.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I think I have worked it out. FMX is very poor!!

Comment: @David - Yeah I did figure that out while looking at WndProc in platform.win. Who in his right mind would call GetCursorPos in a WM_LBUTTONUP?

Comment: @Sertac Indeed. You can see the same in VCL styles where they use Mouse.CursorPos rather than calling GetMessagePos. I've submitted QC reports but nobody seems interested in addressing it. I honestly believe that the authors of most modern Emba library code have limited conceptual understanding of the platforms they are encapsulating. That could be forgiven if the company performed good code review. Clearly they do not.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz One of the bugs fixed in XE5 (!!) was this one: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=117827  Here they use Pythagoras but somehow forget to call `Sqrt` after summing the squares. Mind blowing that this stuff is written in the first place, but then passes through the quality system.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it took till xe5 to get this fixed! thats crazy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with the XE2 FMX framework whose handling of mouse clicks and double clicks appears to be broken. If you click more frequently than your mouse double click interval, then the FMX framework treats all future clicks on a particular cube as double clicks.

The source code is rather revealing. The code that fires your event is here:

```
procedure TControl3D.MouseUp3D(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single; RayPos, RayDir: TVector3D);
begin
  if FAutoCapture then
    ReleaseCapture;
  if FPressed and not(FDoubleClick) and (FIsMouseOver) then
  begin
    FPressed := False;
    Click;
  end;
  if Assigned(FOnMouseUp) then
    FOnMouseUp(Self, Button, Shift, X, Y, RayPos, RayDir);
end;
```

Your problem is that `FDoubleClick` is `True` and that means that `Click` is not firing.

When you click rapidly enough, the framework decides that you are performing a double click. That happens in `TControl3D.MouseDown3D`:

```
if (ssDouble in Shift) then
begin
  DblClick;
  FDoubleClick := True;
end
```

But there is no code anywhere in the unit that sets `FDoubleClick` to `False`. So it seems that once you have double clicked a control, you can never click it again! All future clicks will be interpreted as double clicks.

So, as a quick demonstration that this is the case, connect both `OnClick` and `OnDblClick` of your new cubes to your event handler. This is a rather crude work around to your problem. I suspect, but have not yet verified, that more recent versions of the FMX frame work will resolve the issue. You are working with the initial release which was of lower quality than the most recent releases.

Thanks to Sertac's help in the comments, we can confirm that the flaw was fixed in XE2 update 4. So I posit that you are using an earlier version. I personally am using XE2 update 3. Which, as it happens, is quite lucky for you since I suspect very few XE2 users are, like me, refusing to move on from update 3.

Options to resolve the issue:

- Apply update 4.
- Fix the broken code in your own version of the FMX unit that you compile into your project.

Comment: I think I was able to duplicate the problem with slow clicks, now I can't any more (?). However I can still duplicate it the way you describe, with somewhat frequent periodic clicks. So +1.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz You only need one double click, and then its game over. See my code analysis. Do you concur with that analysis?

Comment: 'FDoubleClick' is set to false in `TControl3D.MouseUp3D`. It's called, a data breakpoint 'CreateCube[##].FDoubleClick' got hit.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Not in the XE2 FMX that I am looking at. Mine looks like this: `procedure TControl3D.MouseUp3D(Button: TMouseButton; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single; RayPos, RayDir: TVector3D);
begin
  if FAutoCapture then
    ReleaseCapture;
  if FPressed and not(FDoubleClick) and (FIsMouseOver) then
  begin
    FPressed := False;
    Click;
  end;
  if Assigned(FOnMouseUp) then
    FOnMouseUp(Self, Button, Shift, X, Y, RayPos, RayDir);
end;
`  I am on update 3 IIRC. And I can see the setting to false in the XE3 source.

Comment: That's different in mine (XE2, update 4). There's `FDoubleClick := False;` just before `FPressed := False;`. Wonder what Glen is running..

Comment: I have update 3. Any suggestion to fix this. With out updating?

Comment: Update 4 is obvious fix. Otherwise you'll need to compile the bogus unit and fix it by adding code that sertac described.

Comment: well you did find out the issue, but yet dont know how to fix it

Comment: before accepting i will wait to see if i get an answer that will fix this issue.

Comment: @Glen - Are you using packages so that you cannot use the fix David suggested? Also, genuinely asking, what's the disadvantage of applying update 4?

Comment: Nothing in the question says, "I have XE2 update 3 and cannot upgrade to update 4".  ;-)  Seriously though, FMX is full of bugs. You are using the initial release. Your life will be much easier with update 4.

Comment: In any case I did tell you how to fix it. Take a copy of the bogus unit. Put it in your project. Fix the code by adding the line that sets FDoubleClick to False. You'll need a copy of the FMX includes file too.

Comment: @GlenMorse Unless you have a need to handle double click separately, then a simple solution as per this answer (without moving to Update 4) is to hook the same event handler to both `OnClick` and `OnDblClick`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan hot fix 4 fixed it, i just hate updateing..seems like it always causes me trouble on other programs... :D

Comment: @DavidHeffernan now when your bored you can finsh my game for me.. D:

Answer (score 0):

- Don't set your `cube.onclick := nil;` and back . This is not necessary.
- Use a global Var : `noEvent`
- Test for `totalblocks` .
  happens only with setting `cube.onclick := nil;` and `fast clicks` . Then it can happen  that, `totalblocks value` changed immediately from e.g. 110 to 21022000 and then   `CreateCube[21022000]:=tcube.Create(self);` throws an exception.

for example :

```
....
countnoEvent : integer;
noEvent      : Boolean;

implementation
....

procedure TForm1.Cube1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  HandleCubeClick(Sender);
end;

Procedure TForm1.HandleCubeClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  cube:TCube;
begin
  if noEvent then exit;
     noEvent:=true;

  cube:= Sender as TCube;
  try
  ....
      label4.Text := 'cubed clicked';
      inc(totalblocks);
      if totalblocks > 600 then begin
        label4.Text := 'max reached : 600 :'+intToStr(totalblocks);
        exit;
      end;
      CreateCube[totalblocks]:=tcube.Create(self);
      CreateCube[totalblocks].Visible := false;
      ....
      CreateCube[totalblocks].Visible := true;
      label4.Text := 'cube made: '+inttostr(totalblocks);
    end;
  finally
    noEvent:=false;
  end;
end;
```

set first CreateCube[totalblocks].Visible := false; (by default true).
If all the properties are set, then set ...[totalblocks].Visible := true;

you can test it

```
  var
  cube:TCube;
  begin
  if noEvent then begin
     inc(countnoEvent);
     exit;
  end;
  ....

      label4.Text := 'cube made: '+inttostr(totalblocks);
      label5.Text := 'noEvent blocked: '+inttostr(countnoEvent);
```

`countnoEvent` will allways be `0` .
That means no run through

```
  if noEvent then begin
     inc(countnoEvent);
```

Comment: This is giveing me the same results, I can click as fast as i want any where on the cube (as long as its not the same exact spot i clicked previous) and it will add a cube, but as soon as i click the same spot (ex I click on cube it adds one. i never move the mouse and just click again. it will not add one. and 90% of the time after that. No matter where i click on that cube it will not add one.  Useing your code it is true that countnoevent is always 0 . Also checked and when this happens the Totalblock count does not go up. and setblock does not go false.